# Difficulties changing permissions for a folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions

I am trying to delete a folder in Windows 7 and I get the following error:

"You need permission to perform this action"

When I go into "Properties" and then the "Security" tab, my username does not show up on the list of "Group or user names". However, if I go into the Advanced Settings and click on "Owner", it says that my username is the current owner. But once again, my username does not show up in the "Permissions" tab.

I am an Administrator. Any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Some screen shots would help us understand your question.
StackExchange uses Imgur for image storage. Upload your image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Answer (score 0):

Being the owner of an object only gives you a very specific kind of access: the ability to read and write the access control list. Before you can delete that folder, you need to use the Permissions tab to add an entry that gives you appropriate privileges - Full Control works fine. (If there's a *Change permissions* button, you'll need to press it first.) If you still have trouble, check the box labeled *Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object*.

[image: corner of the advanced security settings dialog]